# Raphael JS events not firing

Tags: javascript, node.js, user-interface, backbone.js, raphael

I have a Raphael.js icon that I am trying to attach a click even listener to. When I fire the function automatically ( using closure brackets () ) the console log is successful. However, I cannot fire the event with no automatic execution of the function. Is there an known bug/issue with transforms that puts the rendered path elsewhere on the page? I've poured through comments here, if anyone has seen a similar issue please post.

```
              var paper3 = Raphael($("#mail").get(0), 175, 75);
              var iconPath3 = paper3.path(iconPath);
              iconPath3.transform("s1.3, t0,5");
              iconPath3.attr("fill","fff");
              iconPath3.click(function(e) {
                  console.log("Test");
              });
```

Comment: I'd put the example with the code on a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping iconPath3 in a jQuery object:

```
$(iconPath3).click(function(e){
     console.log("Logging event: ", e);
});
```

Also, have you tried setting fill using a JavaScript object:

```
iconPath3.attr({fill: '#fff'});
```

Hope that helps.